# React, Tailwind css, Swiper, remove previous image from swiper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to load images from listings and everything is working great but when i slide to the next picture the previous image stays there under (stacking over each other). Could someone please help me resolve this?

```
return(
listings && 
( <> 
<div className='mt-2'>
<Swiper slidesPerView={1} navigation pagination={{type: 'progressbar'}} effect='fade' modules={[EffectFade]} autoplay={{delay:3000}}>
{listings.map(({data, id}) => (
<SwiperSlide key={id} onClick={() => navigate(/kategori/${data.type}/${id})}>
<div style={{background: url(${data.imgUrls[0]}) center/contain no-repeat,}} className='relative w-full h-[300px] mt-4 overflow-hidden'>
      
    </div>
    </SwiperSlide>
    ))} 
    </Swiper>
    </div>
</>
)
}
```

I've tried adding .update() and i know there is a thing where i can type delete but i didn't manage to get it working. Please help me!

Comment: Seems like the background is being to set to the URL of your first image from `data` ?, maybe it's the background that's remaining constant?

Comment: I don’t think that the image being a constant is the problem. It’s getting the images from a list and it works to scroll through them but it’s not removing the last picture. If i for example fetch 6 images and scroll through them they all stack on each other. I want them to be hidden after scrolling to the next picture

Comment: Can anyone please help?